# Security exception when connecting Android app to server

Tags: android, securityexception

I am using the `http://android.toolib.net/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html` as an base when making my own connection to a server from my Android app. I have changed the url and created a username and password on the server for access. WHen I try to connect I get this error, with or without the correct password.

Where does this come from? It shouldn't matter to the server, but is on the server side, right?

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1630): java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10024 is different than the authenticator's uid .
```

THanks for help!

Comment: It is on the client side. I guess you forgot to add some permission to your manifest.